# What is the purpose of the comments in the YAML of a task in the build pipeline visual designer?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

When I look in the YAML for a task in the visual designer of my build pipeline I see comments like

```
#Your build pipeline references an undefined variable named ‘Parameters.projects’. Create or edit the build pipeline for this YAML file, define the variable on the Variables tab. See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=865972
```

Is this an instruction to me to add the Parameters.projects variable or is it just something that is there for me to refer to should I decide to use the YAML in constructing a YAML build pipeline?

Comment: The generated YAML, still to this day, does not give you the parameters, variables and vmImage. Nor does it alert you to the fact it omits this YAML from the output... Basically, these comments are somewhat misleading. Yes, these variables/parameters are undefined- because nobody has taken the time to write the code to include the initialization of these parameters/variables in the YAML generator... You need to add the missing parameters, variables and vmImage to the generated YAML to get the pipeline up-and-running. These values can be discovered by reviewing the classic editor's interface.

Comment: 'Tasks > Pipeline > Agent Specification' will show you the vmImage value. 'Tasks > Pipeline > Parameters' will show you the necessary parameters. Finally, 'Variables > Pipeline variables' will show you the variables.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Those are more a kind of instruction to the users in order to understand the flow.

E.g.:

Here the parameter (`parameters.solution`) is linked to the value `**\*.sln`

[image]

The YAML for this is

```
#Your build pipeline references an undefined variable named ‘Parameters.solution’. Create or edit the build pipeline for this YAML file, define the variable on the Variables tab. See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=865972
#Your build pipeline references the ‘BuildPlatform’ variable, which you’ve selected to be settable at queue time. Create or edit the build pipeline for this YAML file, define the variable on the Variables tab, and then select the option to make it settable at queue time. See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=865971
#Your build pipeline references the ‘BuildConfiguration’ variable, which you’ve selected to be settable at queue time. Create or edit the build pipeline for this YAML file, define the variable on the Variables tab, and then select the option to make it settable at queue time. See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=865971
steps:
- task: VSBuild@1
  displayName: 'Build solution'
  inputs:
    solution: '$(Parameters.solution)'

    msbuildArgs: '/p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:WebPublishMethod=Package /p:PackageAsSingleFile=true /p:SkipInvalidConfigurations=true /p:PackageLocation="$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)\\"'

    platform: '$(BuildPlatform)'

    configuration: '$(BuildConfiguration)'
```

Now I'm going to unlink the default value of this variable and point towards my `sln` file.

[image]

If I see the YAML file now the variable `Parameters.solution` is no longer needed, since the solution is directly assigned to the `wcfapp.sln`. **In this case you will not see any comment in your YAML file**

```
#Your build pipeline references the ‘BuildPlatform’ variable, which you’ve selected to be settable at queue time. Create or edit the build pipeline for this YAML file, define the variable on the Variables tab, and then select the option to make it settable at queue time. See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=865971
#Your build pipeline references the ‘BuildConfiguration’ variable, which you’ve selected to be settable at queue time. Create or edit the build pipeline for this YAML file, define the variable on the Variables tab, and then select the option to make it settable at queue time. See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=865971
steps:
- task: VSBuild@1
  displayName: 'Build solution'
  inputs:
    solution: wcfapp.sln

    msbuildArgs: '/p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:WebPublishMethod=Package /p:PackageAsSingleFile=true /p:SkipInvalidConfigurations=true /p:PackageLocation="$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)\\"'

    platform: '$(BuildPlatform)'

    configuration: '$(BuildConfiguration)'
```

Comment: So does this mean, the build can still contain the value assigned for the variable when I initiate it or still undefined?